# Как открыть фрагмент по нажатию на уведомление?

Tags: android

Есть 1 класс с активити(мейн) и 1 класс-фрагмент. Прилка имеет 3 кнопки, -/+/создать уведомление.
"+" создаёт фрагмент
"-" удаляет фрагмент
Нужно по нажатию на уведомление открыть тот фрагмент, в котором было создано уведомление, т.е. нажата кнопка "создать уведомление". Для активити это работает на ура. Как это сделать для фрагмента?

Comment: Не вполне ясно в чем у вас проблема. Фрагмент можно через менеджер фрагментов найти и новой транзакцией отобразить

Comment: "страница"-фраг
В приложении будут 3 разные кнопки:

1) «+» эта кнопка создаст новый фрагмент с максимальным номером фрагмента +1
Например, нажатие «+» на фрагменте 1 создаст страницу с номером 2. повторное нажатие создаст страницу с номером 3 и так далее.
2) «Создать новое уведомление» - при нажатии на эту кнопку будет создано уведомление с текстом «уведомление и номер страницы».
Например: если вы нажмете его на странице с номером 10, будет создано уведомление с текстом «Уведомление 10».
3) Кнопка удаления «-» удаляет фрагмент и все уведомления, которые были созданы из этого фрагмента.

Comment: При нажатии на уведомление откроется фрагмент с тем же номером страницы, на которой это уведомление было создано.

Comment: Очень много вопросов по поводу точности ТЗ) Однако, давайте декомпозируем задачу. Как я понимаю, ваш вопрос, в общем-то, только о том, как программно прореагировать на нажатие на уведомление в активити?

Comment: Вопрос в следующем. Как по нажатию на уведомление открыть фрагмент, а не активити? И возможно ли такое?)

Comment: Вообще из уведомления фрагмент открыть нельзя. Однако, вы можете открыть актвити, в ней выполниться onCreate\onNewIntent метод, в нём вы можете вытащить из Intent что-то, например номер нужного вам фрагмента и в зависимости от этого через менеджер фрагментов открыть тот или иной фрагмент

Comment: Окей, спасибо за инфу! Очень признателен! Буду пробовать, отпишу, когда получиться)

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть в сторону deeplink + navigation

Comment: Всё это будет работать с ViewPager2? В итоге нужно что бы это всё было внутри viewpager2

Comment: Цель о открыть фрагмент или активити, и получить информацию из сообщения, а потом ту информацию обработать и открыть нужную страницу во ViewPager. По умолчанию через нотификашку можно запустить только активити, Но использую navigation, можно еще в нутри этой активити запустить нужный фрагмент